# Assets precompilation requires database connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, heroku, virtual, assets

Issue appears when using virtual attribute validation:

```
validates :agreement, acceptance: true
```

When removing it, assets precompilation no longer requires a database connection.
Any ideas how to save validation and do not precompile assets locally?

Comment: Seems to be a bug (feature?) in rails 4. Rails github issue - https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11853

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

Prevent assets being precompiled when initializing your application in config/application.rb

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

or allow them to be initialized and add the heroku labs user-env-compile:

```
heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp
```

Read more:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile

Comment: `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`  
was removed in rails 4  
`heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a myapp`  
works, but i want to figure issue's reason.

Comment: your original question didn't specify a Rails version. Are you using the rails_12factor gem?

Comment: Rails 4, no assets group, rails_12factor gem in production group. Everything was fine and all validations worked (not virtual attributes), after adding virtual attribute validation assets precompilcation requires a database connection.

Comment: Rails is looking to see if the class has a matching attribute to the acceptance attribute (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/acceptance.rb#L18) which is why it's trying to look up the schema. It could be a bug in Rails that it isn't doing this against schema.rb rather than what it seems like it is doing which is hitting the database.

Comment: @x3qt you can add an attr_accessor to add the virtual attribute before the validation to avoid this problem.